# 2 way data binding between directive and controller fails. Why?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I created a plink to illustrate my question:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qwxXzIgBdb3C8MH4FleG?p=preview

I have a directive and a controller.  I'd like to send down a list of users from the controller to the directive. No problems there.

```
app.controller('Controller',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.users = [
    {name:'Jason', id:'1'}, 
    {name:'Kris', id:'2'},
    {name: 'John', id:'3'}
    ];

  $scope.activeUser = $scope.users[0];
}]);

app.directive('myDirective', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      people: '=',
      selectedUser:'=',
    },
    templateUrl:'directive.html'
  };
});
```

In my index.html I bind users to people and activeUser to selectedUser.

```
 <my-directive people="users" selectedUser="activeUser"></my-directive>
```

Inside the directive is a dropdown select box where you can select a user.  I bind the model of the select tag to selectedUser, and thus to activUser (or at least that's my understanding.  It's not working so clearly I'm missing something).

```
<select ng-options="person.name for person in people" ng-model='selectedUser'>
```

When I select someone from the dropdown I expect to see the change reflected outside the directive in the activeUser variable, like so:

```
<my-directive people="users" selectedUser="activeUser"></my-directive>

      <p>outside of the directive:</p>
      {{activeUser}}
```

This isn't happening though.  Why not?

P.S. I'd like to use ng-change to fire off an http call to a database, so I can't use it as work around.  More importantly though, what I have really SHOULD work, and I'd like to understand why it doesn't.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though there's an issue with the directive itself, which is inhibiting the two-way data binding:

**Current**

```
<my-directive people="users" selectedUser="activeUser"></my-directive>
```

**Expected**

```
<my-directive people="users" selected-user="activeUser"></my-directive>
```

Note the missing dash (`-`) in the first directive above. As a result, the data from the controller was NOT being passed to the directive, which means there was no two-way binding. This is even more noticeable when we realize that the directive itself (both the text input field, and the select field) were not defaulting to `Jason` even though he was the active user being passed in.

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RcziLDlBneT4bjqD5BPJ

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, that works!  Do you have an explanation for why the way I was trying wasn't working?  It really seems to me like I'm essentially making selectedUser and activeUser the same variable.  This makes sense with all the research I've done around '='.  Obviously it's not correct though.

Comment: Just updated the answer the actual problem. Not sure how I missed this, I guess I figured the directive HTML wouldn't have been the issue!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of combing over everything I found the issue.  This is, I think, clearly the most elegant solution.  Thank you for your help Lux!

```
<my-directive people="users" selected-user="activeUser"></my-directive>
```

Notice 'selected-user' instead of 'selectedUser' that I had in the original plink.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dSVYj9zwK7YlS4gavgPE?p=preview

Comment: We must have found this in unison! Updated my answer and saw you found it as well. Good stuff!